# Original panda data is showing up after I use the filter one with groupby().size()

Tags: python

All values in data (original data) show up in the new_data even though I am using the filtered data where I have sliced the data.

```
data_filtered = data[data['Column C']=='some_value']
data_filtered = data_filtered.reset_index(drop = True)

new_data = data_filtered.groupby(['Column A','Column B'],as_index=False].size().sort_values(by=['size'])
```

Comment: Please do share the dataframe you are working on or a sample data similar to it.

Comment: it is jus ta regular data frame. values are strings. there is nothing special about it.